# Why is the Y axis inverted on my touchscreen calibrated with xinput_calibrator?

Tags: display, touchscreen, xorg

I am using a raspberry Pi B+ rev1.2 with a 1024x600 7inch HDMI touchscreen and I'm having trouble getting the touchscreen to work

So first of I installed waveshareLCDDriver, runned sudo ./LCD7-1024x600-show and got an  Unable to connect to X server : connection refused error when launching startx.
After looking at the logs, i've fixed it by installing fbturbo https://github.com/ssvb/xf86-video-fbturbo/wiki/Installation and now my GUI work.

Then I do apt-get install xinput-calibrator and run sudo DISPLAY=:0 xinput_calibrator --output-filename /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf. But I end up with  baddly calibrated touchscreen axis: When I drag my finger left and right the cursor moves up and down and when I drag my finger up and down, the cursor goes left and right.

So I tried editing 99-calibration.conf, changing the values of the SwapXY, InvertX, InvertY and rebooting but didn't work

I tried changing the Identity Matrix of the Coordinate Transformation Matrix to [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1] to swap my X axis and Y axis and it kinda work. Now I have a X axis working, i can move my finger right and left and the cursor follows but when I move my finger up, cursor goes down and when I move my finger down cursor goes up...

What should I try now ?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation

Comment: Already tried that, fixes the X axis but not the Y axis, as mentionned above in the original post